# How to use JSON Object as the source for the Jquery Autocomplete?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to feed the textbox with the JSON which is a key value pair

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var aTags = [
    {
      "SYMBOL": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "SYMBOL": "XYZ"
    }
  ]

  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: aTags."SYMBOL";
  });

});
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/9R4cV/469/

Could you please let me know how to resolve this .

Comment: Your `source` needs to either be an array of strings or an array of objects.  It's an array of objects, they need to be in this format `{label: '', value: ''}`. See: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source.  You'll need to convert your array into the proper format.

Comment: @Preethi You know how to write better questions and read docs for that plugin. Really not clear what you want here especially since data format doesn't match the docs

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues with your fiddle.

```
source: aTags."SYMBOL";
```

This is illegal JS. Use bracket notation, and don't use semi-colons inside objects.

```
source: aTags[arrayIndex]["SYMBOL"]
```

And as per your fiddle, jQuery autocomplete is a UI plugin. You need to load it in otherwise the method does not exist.

Comment: Thanks , I have got 6000 symbols , how can i keep array in this case

Answer (score 0):

`aTags` is an array of objects. So, you have 2 `SYMBOL`s value:

```
aTags[0].SYMBOL
aTags[1]['SYMBOL']
```

Please note, both of the above are same, except first refers to `ABC` and the latter to `XYZ`.